# first order weak derivative of function $ f(x) = |x| $

Tags: sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

let $f(x)= |x| $ how can I calculate the first order weak derivative of this function in $x=0$?
Does anyone have an idea on how to calculate this?

Answer (score 4):

The direct answer is that since the weak derivative of a function is only defined *almost everywhere*, you can put whatever value of $f'(0)$ you want.

Always, remember that we say $g$ is the weak derivative of $f(x)=|x|$ if for any $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R)$, we have 
$$ \int_{\mathbb R} f\,\phi'\,dx=-\int_{\mathbb R}g\,\phi\,dx \tag 1$$

Hence, define
$$
f'(x)= 
\begin{cases}
1&x>0\\
-1&x<0\\
\alpha&x=0
\end{cases}
$$
where $\alpha\in \mathbb R$ is an arbitrary constant, can you verify $(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

$$f'(x)=-H(-x)+H(x)$$ where $H(x)=0$ when $-\infty\lt x\leq 0$ and $H(x)=1$ when $x\gt 0$

Comment: would you please explain your answer ?

Comment: Wherever the classical derivative is defined, it equals the weak derivative. So in our case the derivative for positive $x$ is $+1$ and the derivative for negative $x$ is $-1$. We have an issue for $x=0$ but absolute value is continuous and has a derivative at $0^+$ and a different one at $0^-$. Pick one of them. Had we had a discontinuity we would have had a multiple of a Dirac measure there.